# Can I limit JMF Player memory usage?

Tags: java, jmf

I'm using Java JMF to read videos and get frames from them. As far as I know, a Player loads the whole media in memory, which cannot be very convenient for large files.

Is there any way to limit the resource loading, or the memory consumption? I understand the process would require more disk reading, but I think it is a fair trade.

Answer (score 1):

One basic approach would be to limit the heap size of the JVM for this application when you run the Java application.

You can use the -Xmx Flag with the 'java' command to do this:

> -Xmx

For example:

> java -Xmx512m myVideoApp

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, if the whole video does not fit in memory, would this flag make the program load it in chunks, or wouldn't it  run at all?

Comment: If a program needs more memory than is available it should run anyway but more slowly as it will have to swap in and out chunks. As an aside, very few videos will be small enough to be loaded into memory, and there is no real point in doing so anyway for playback as you only need enough in the buffer for to display the current section of the video (plus whatever you include in the buffer). I probably should have said this first, come to think of it!

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. I will try that flag as soon as I can and I will post the results.